# Can't replace linebreaks in an mysql error string

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling, prepared-statement

I try to catch erros from a prepared MySQL statement.

```php
try {
    if ($stmt = $this->db->prepare($q)) {
    array_unshift($sqlData, $sqlTypes); // prepend the types
        if(call_user_func_array([$stmt, 'bind_param'], $sqlData)) {
            try {
                $stmt->execute();
                $r = $stmt->get_result();
                return $r;
            } catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e2) {
            // request error
            $err = error_get_last();
            $this->return['error'][] = $stmt->error;
            $this->return['error'][] = $err;
            $this->return['error'][] = $stmt->error_list;
            }
        } else {
            // sql statement bind error
            $this->return['error'][] = 'SQL bind error: ' . $this->db->error;
            $this->return['message'][] = 'endpoint: SQL bind Error';
        }
    } else {
        // sql statement error
        $this->return['error'][] = 'SQL statement Error: ' . $this->db->error;
        $this->return['message'][] = 'endpoint: SQL statement Error';
    }
} catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e1) {
    // sql query error
    $this->return['error'][] = $this->db->error;
    $this->return['message'][] = 'endpoint: Query error';
}
```

I add an error to the SQL statement to test the function.
The `$this->db->error` in the `catch` part got it as a string.
I send the whole `$this->return` via `json_encode` to my site and try to `JSON.parse` it. JS is triggering following error: **Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list.**

The mysql error itself is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM
> `mytable`
> LEFT JOIN `da...' at line 14

The json encoded string of this is:

> ["You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM \r\n                    `mytable`\r\n                    LEFT JOIN `da...' at line 14"]

So the php json_encode fails. It seems, that the problem are the linebreaks in the mysql error text.

Pretty easy to solve? Nope.
`str_replace('\r\n', '', $err)` - fails
nl2br - fails

still '\r\n' inside of the string. nl2br does its job and put some br into position, but '\r\n' follows that html linebreak

I thougt about wrong character encoding or so, but the string is ASCII - which seems to be part of UTF-8

I have no idea why I cant remove the linebreaks in the json encoded string. I can't reproduce that with any other string except the one coming from the mysql error.

Comment: Why on earth are you trying to do this? Unless you're actually building a database management tool (similar to phpmyadmin or something), then you should **never** be reporting sensitive error information such as SQL info back to the client-side on purpose. In a development environment you can allow PHP to throw the exception and show it in the output, but in a live environment PHP must be configured to log such error to a file on the server instead, so they aren't publicly visible. And you must enable mysqli error reporting mode, if it isn't already enabled.

Comment: Read https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli#error_handling and then https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting to learn about a sane, easy way to handle errors without all this messing about, and without the security concerns.

Comment: There is no `json_encode()` in your code, so we cannot be sure what you're actually doing.

Comment: `'\r\n'` <> `"\r\n"` but other points raised here should be considered first. Look at `str_replace(['\n', "\n"], ['backslash', 'new line'], 'test' . PHP_EOL . 'TEST')` if unclear what I mean. You `nl2br` and `str_replace` usage also is not in the question so hard to tell what you actually are doing.

Comment: its just: json_encode($this->return['error']);

Comment: Its just a debug thing in my dev environment. No output in the live Environment

Comment: You can debug in the dev environment by simply enabling mysqli error reporting and letting PHP throw the errors. There's still no need for all this complexity. Frankly a mysqli error should only happen very occasionally, even when developing, so it's a lot of effort for minimal usage.

Comment: You'll never know...

Comment: Anyway, the linebreaks aren't the cause. See: https://3v4l.org/NHcEs What we need is a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please edit your question. If your question can be answered, it will likely be reopened.

Comment: `You'll never know`...not sure what you mean?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try it like this:
str_replace(["\r\n", "\n", "\r"], ' ', $err);

And otherwise check your string with this:
echo bin2hex($err);

what is the return?

Comment: Holy - job done. But why " instead of '?